# Fixed point free automorphism (Order 2)

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to start the proof that states:

Given $G$ with an automorphism $\sigma$ with no fixed points and $\sigma^2 = 1$, show that $G$ is Abelian.

The crux of the proof relies upon showing an element g $\in$ $G$ can be written as $x^{-1}\sigma(x)$.

My work:

I need to show that if $x^{-1}\sigma(x) = y^{-1}\sigma(y)  \implies x = y$.  This would lead to the mapping $x \rightarrow x^{-1}\sigma(x)$.

Since $\sigma(x) = x \implies x = e$, for $x = e$ we know that $\sigma(e) = 1 = y^{-1}\sigma(y) \implies y = e = x$.

But I can only show that this holds for the identity.  In what way can I extend the argument for all x?

Comment: Automorphisms always fix the identity of a group, so  you must explicity state that there are no **non identity** fixed points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x^{-1} \sigma(x) = y^{-1} \sigma(y)$.
Then $yx^{-1} = \sigma(y) \sigma(x)^{-1}$. The right-hand side is $\sigma(yx^{-1})$. So $y x^{-1}$ is a fixed point of $\sigma$.

Comment: Why does this imply every element of $G$ can be written as $x^{-1} \sigma (x)$ for some $x \in G$? And why does any of this prove that $G$ is abelian?

Comment: Hint to show abelian: show that if $g = x^{-1} \sigma(x)$ for some $x$, then $\sigma(g^{-1}) = g$. (Then apply this fact to $gh$.) Honestly though, the best I have for your first question is "if $G$ is finite then it's true because an injection from a finite set to itself is a bijection".

Comment: Ah, I see. I was right in thinking that this solution works only when $G$ is finite. Actually, for an infinite non-abelian example, if $G = \langle a,b \rangle$ is freely generated by $a$ and $b$, then $\sigma$ defined as the homomorphic extension of $a \mapsto b$ and $b \mapsto a$. Clearly this is surjective and therefore an automorphism, because $G$ is Hopfian. And then playing with words in $a$ and $b$, it seems pretty clear that it's of order $2$ and is fixed-point-free...right? Unless I made mistake which is almost always within the realm of possibility...

Comment: @user193319 Yeah, I agree with you.